# How can I avoid infinite number of operations at Towers of Hanoi

Tags: python, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I need to calculate the number of steps required to solve the Towers of Hanoi problem (with the help of recursion). My script only works with smaller number of disks but if I try something like 12 it shows that I need an infinite number of operations to calculate the result. I cannot figure out where my mistake is:

```
steps = 0

def req_steps(num_disks):
    global steps
    if num_disks >= 1:
        req_steps(num_disks - 1)
        #steps += 1
        req_steps(num_disks - 1)
        steps += 1
        return steps
    return -1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(3, req_steps(12))
```

Comment: @dmitryro You subtly broke the indentation (see my edit fixing it). Please try to be more careful in the future, especially for languages like Python where it matters.

Comment: @Joseph Sible Thanks for noticing. Will do.

Comment: @total_rookie This displays `3` and `4095` for me. Are you sure the code you posted here is the same as the code you're running?

Comment: @JosephSible I tried it in the online visualizer. Now I see that it actually works but there is still a mistake. According to the formula 2^n-1 it should be 2048 moves for 12 disks.

Comment: perhaps there was also an error of indentation in the initial question.

Answer (score 1):

To calculate the number of moves for the towers of Hanoi, there's (at least) three approaches.

1.) Solve Towers of Hanoi and use a global var to count

- add a global var to act as counter
- Implement a solution to the towers of Hanoi,
- remove all the print statements
- increment the global counter at each place where you would have moved a disk

Now to run this solution.
reset the global var to 0, run your script and check the result of the global at the end

2.) Implement Towers of Hanoi and let the function return the number of moves for each solution (and just remove the print statements)

This solution is in my opinion cleaner, as it does not require a global.

3.) Don't write a program, but just make a mathematical prove, that the solution is 2**n -1 (The approach is called mathematical induction)

Attached The solution for 2.)

```
def req_steps(num_disks):
    if num_disks > 1:
        steps = req_steps(num_disks - 1)
        steps += req_steps(num_disks - 1)
        steps += 1
        return steps
    return 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for i in range(1,13):
        print("%2d %4d %4d" % (i, req_steps(i), 2 ** i - 1))
```

The output should look:

```
 1    1    1
 2    3    3
 3    7    7
 4   15   15
 5   31   31
 6   63   63
 7  127  127
 8  255  255
 9  511  511
10 1023 1023
11 2047 2047
12 4095 4095
```